# How to ask a question that is almost a duplicate of another?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask a question on SO but found a very similar one. No answer has been chosen though and indeed the provided answers do not work (for me neither).

I am hesitating to start a bounty though because the way this old question is formulated is not satisfying for me: from my point of view it's a bit too particular example. I would write this question another way, including a precise and simple [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I think this way it would be easier to answer to it.

So, I cannot edit the old question and change it completely.

But if I add the question the way I think it should be asked, it would be a duplicate. Should I write it and precise it's a duplicate (or rather a reformulation) of the other question?

Starting a bounty would be an option if I found the question was satisfyingly explained. How it is now, I am afraid it won't draw enough attention (even with a bounty) nor the "right" people to answer it.

What is the best to do?

---

EDIT: The old unanswered question:

[Sphinx's .. include:: directive and "duplicate label" warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262163/sphinxs-include-directive-and-duplicate-label-warnings)

and here is my version:

> I want to separate some portions of the sphinx documentation in
>   several files to avoid having too long files to edit, and hence use
>   the `include` directive. Problem is, when I want to use a reference
>   between two included files, I get this warning:
>
> ```
> source/doc2_content.rst:4: WARNING: duplicate label doc2_label, other instance in
> ```
>
> /home/nico/temp/essai_py/project/myproject/docs/source/doc2_content.rst
>
> Despite the fact that the link works correctly, I don't want to
>   silent the warning, nor to ignore it (in my real project, there are
>   several such warnings and I think I could miss some important warning
>   if I just get accustomed to see them all the time).
>
> To reproduce it, start a documentation project in a fake empty
>   project, using `sphinx-quickstart` (inside of a dedicated brand-new
>   venv), keep all default values (put some dummy string for stuff like
>   "author's name"...).
>
> Here are the files to add|edit in the `project/docs/` folder:
>
> ```
> .
> ├── doc1.rst
> ├── doc2_content.rst
> ├── doc2.rst
> └── index.rst
> ```
>
> And their content (all other files being generated by `sphinx`):
>
> `doc1.rst`:
>
> ```
> First doc1 title
> ================
>
> Some content. See also :ref:`doc2_label`
> ```
>
> `doc2.rst`:
>
> ```
> First doc2 title
> ================
>
> Lorem ipsum etc.
>
> .. include:: doc2_content.rst
> ```
>
> `doc2_content.rst`:
>
> ```
> .. _doc2_label:
>
> First doc2 subtitle
> -------------------
>
> Hello world!
> ```
>
> `index.rst`:
>
> ```
> .. myproject documentation master file, created by
>    sphinx-quickstart on Sat Jul  2 08:40:01 2016.
>    You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
>
>    contain the root `toctree` directive.
>
> Welcome to myproject's documentation!
> =====================================
>
> Contents:
>
> .. toctree::
>    :maxdepth: 2
>
>    doc1
>    doc2
>
>
>
> Indices and tables
> ==================
>
> * :ref:`genindex`
> * :ref:`modindex`
> * :ref:`search`
> ```
>
> Finally, type `make html`

Comment: Rather than trying to answer in the abstract, could you give a link to the old question and a draft of your proposed new version?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thought this would be too long. Just added it.